# WordPress: Replace custom URL structure for posts in specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

In Dashboard->Settings, I have Custom Structure for my Posts set to `myurl.com/blog/%postname%/`

This currently works as intended for all individual Posts, but for Posts with a specific category (in this case, "testimonials"), I would like to change it to be: `myurl.com/testimonials/the-post-slug`

I tried using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/, and while this works great for setting a custom URL for the top-level Category page, it seems like I would still need to manually set each the custom URL structure for each individual Post, which is not ideal.

I'd like to accomplish this without needing to register a new Post type, as there are currently a lot of Posts in the "testimonials" category and I do not want to need to worry about new loop templates or anything like that.

Comment: You can add  Custom Structure = "/%category%/%postname%/" in permalink settings.

Comment: Currently, for the sake of this website, I need to have Custom Structure set to "/blog/%postname%/". Essentially, for Posts with the category "testimonial", I need to remove the "/blog/" and replace it with "/testimonial/%postname%/"

Comment: See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/296287/137402).